# Count is not returning the proper value

Tags: c

I defined a struct (bldg) which has a variable (int classroom[5][40]) and my function that counts the remaining available seats (40) is not returning the proper value.

```c
#define MAX_ROOMS 5 
#define MAX_OCCUPANTS 40 

typedef struct bldg{
    int classroom[MAX_ROOMS][MAX_OCCUPANTS];
    int seminarRoom[MAX_ROOMS][MAX_OCCUPANTS];
    int auditorium[MAX_ROOMS][MAX_OCCUPANTS];
    int trainingRoom[MAX_ROOMS][MAX_OCCUPANTS];
} bldg;

void displayAvailableRooms(const bldg *ag)
{
    printf("Available Seats in Classrooms:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROOMS; i++)
    {
        int availableSeats = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_OCCUPANTS; j++)
        {
            if (ag->classroom[i][j] == 0)
            {
                availableSeats++;
            }
        }
        printf("Classroom %d: %d seats available\n", i + 1, availableSeats);
    }
}

int main()
{
    bldg A;
    displayAvailableRooms(&A);
    return 0; 
}
```

Output

```
Available Seats in Classrooms:
Classroom 1: 17 seats available
Classroom 2: 13 seats available
classroom 3: 21 seats available
Classroom 4: 19 seats available
classroom 5: 17 seats available
```

It's supposed to be 40 for all rooms since they are all empty but I keep getting these outputs. I need help.

Comment: why do you expect zeros in that array, where do you set it to zero?

Comment: I just assumed that by defining the struct bldg: int classroom[5][40] would have 5 classrooms with 40 capacity and since I haven't filled the array yet, there should be no values inside the array

Comment: how do i do that? i am sorry, im new in coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in your arrays are uninitialized and thus indeterminate, and thus so will the value of `availableSeats` be indeterminate. Given that it's a signed int, you could even get overflow behavior.

If you expect those values to be set to `0`, you have to do it explicitly.

```
int main()
{
    bldg A;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROOMS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_OCCUPANTS; j++) 
            A->classroom[i][j] = 0;

    displayAvailableRooms(&A);
    return 0; 
}
```

You will probably want to break this out into a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to initialising the arrays [within loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689928/1312382) you can also provide initialisers:

```
bldg A =
{
        .classroom    = { { 0 } },
        .seminarRoom  = { { 0 } },
        .auditorium   = { { 0 } },
        .trainingRoom = { [2] = { [7] = 1 } },
};
```

Note that it suffices to initialise one element of the array, that could as well be somewhere in the middle (just for illustration I did so at the training rooms, one single seat in one single training room will be occupied…) – all array elements not explicitly specified will be initialised to 0.